# Is there a way to set the composer cache dir in windows?

Tags: composer-php

Anyone know how to set the composer cache directory in windows?

I am running a 'composer install' from git hook and i get this:

```
remote: Cannot create cache directory C:/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile/AppData/Local/Composer/rremote: s---packages.drupal.org-8/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
```

remote: Cannot create

I installed composer for the .exe installer on the website. The documentation https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#cache-dir says it's suppose to point to C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Composer.

Answer (score 2):

Composer has a [`cache-dir`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#cache-dir) configuration which makes it possible to change the path of the cache folder. Did you actually try to change the cache directory with it? Maybe Composer somehow wrongly resolves the default cache folder.

You can also try changing the [`COMPOSER_HOME`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home) environment variable.

Comment: But where and how do you set the COMPOSER_HOME and COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR variables?